# $3\times3$ Game Theory Problem without numeric numbers

Tags: optimization, game-theory

[image]

This table looks simple but I don't know how to calculate the mixed strategies and the value of the game. I tried to write down the linear program but find unable to solve it. Is there any hint or thoughts? One thing to check first, it does not have a pure strategy, right?

Comment: You should mark the answer as accepted ($\color{\limegreen}{\checkmark}$).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

If you assume the optimal strategy of the chooser of the rows assigns *positive* weight to every one of his pure strategies, and the value of the game to that player is $\ v\ $, then the optimal mixed strategy $\ (p_1,p_2,p_3)\ $ must satisfy
\begin{align}
v&=ap_1=bp_2=cp_3\ \ \text{, and}\\
1&=p_1+p_2+p_3
\end{align}

Comment: I have set variables like p1, p2, p3, but I'm not sure how to solve them, using the given abc to represent their value...

Comment: Unless you're given explicit numerical values for $\ a\ $, $\ b\ $ and $\ c\ $ you can only get $\ v\ $, $\ p_1\ $, $\ p_2\ $ and $\ p_3\ $ as functions of those quantities.  My first three equations  enable you to express $\ p_1\ $, $\ p_2\ $ and $\ p_3\ $ in terms of $\ v\ $, $\ a\ $, $\ b\ $ and $\ c\ $ $(\ p_1=\frac{v}{a}\ $, for instance).  Substituting those expressions for $\ p_1\ $, $\ p_2\ $ and $\ p_3\ $ into the fourth equation gives you a linear equation in just the one variable $\ v\ $, which you can solve to express $\ v\ $ as a function of $\ a\ $, $\ b\ $ and $\ c\ $.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I thought I must construct a linear program to solve for p, and now it seems the only way to represent p is what you say.

Comment: So, p1,p2, and p3 for both players are the same?

Comment: Yes, that's right.